# Несколько значений where

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT `date_modify`, `product_ean` FROM `diz_jshopping_products` WHERE `product_ean` in (".(string)$data.") AND `product_publish` = '1' GROUP BY DATE(date_modify) DESC LIMIT ".$start.", 1
```

содержание `$data = '22-319','1042','1022','1119','1026','W8696','ST7018','W8020'`
выдает ошибку в этой части запроса, что не так?

Запрос после компиляции:

```
SELECT `date_modify`, `product_ean` FROM `diz_jshopping_products` WHERE `product_ean` in ('22-319','1042','1022','1119','1026','W8696','ST7018','W8020') AND `product_publish` = '1' GROUP BY DATE(date_modify) DESC LIMIT 32, 1
```

даже так не работает [Скрин](http://truwa.ru/screenshot/opera_2017-07-21_15-19-58.png)

Comment: распечатайте запрос каким он получается после подстановки значения переменных

Comment: @Mike, добавил запрос после компиляции

Comment: Хм. выглядит правильным. а сообщение об ошибке какое

Comment: @Mike ниже в ответе есть

Comment: на другой версии mysql попробуйте

Comment: @Alex78191 может просто забить на решение задачи?
Плохой совет

Comment: SQL запрос верный, есть статус закрытия вопросв - не воспроизводится.

Comment: В запросе используется `GROUP BY DATE(date_modify) DESC`. Попробуйте убрать `DESC` - быть может дело в этом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = ['22-319','1042','1022','1119','1026','W8696','ST7018','W8020'];
$in = '(' . implode(',', $data) .')';
```

запрос

```
SELECT `date_modify`, `product_ean` FROM `diz_jshopping_products` WHERE `product_ean` in " . $in . " AND `product_publish` = '1' GROUP BY DATE(date_modify) DESC LIMIT ".$start.", 1
```

Comment: а запрос после компиляции можно? не вижу разницы просто

Comment: `Ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''22-319','1042','1022','1119','1026','W8696','ST7018','W8020','F8016','F5120','C' at line 1`

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков ошибка пропала что ли?